# Strange Crash in base.apk (offset 0xc07000) Android

Tags: android

My application...  had a little crash report..
But in April 15... One user ,Android 8.1, Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte) have reported 35 times this report
in  base.apk (offset 0xc07000) ,   #00  pc 0000000001c8631c  /data/app/com.android.chrome-BQ5-Eow4fyhZkTpWvtTpOA==/base.apk (offset 0xc07000)

Firebase Crashlytic  does not show this crash... But Play console thus

I didt get what cause this crash, any help appreciated

***Application = Yaz Köşesi***

[image: first_pict]

[image: second picture]

On the way invistigating, My another application  has also have this crash reports.. They are common to use Webview...

***Application Page Direction***

[image: third picture]

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: Added pictures..

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Nope .................

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I downloaded my Samsung Galaxy S8 device specific APK in google play console app bundle explorer. I ran "base.apk" and it wouldn't finish installing. Many of my apps started crashing (e.g. Gmail, Fitbit). What fixed it was disabling Google chrome.